# Data Driven Switch and Case PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to build a switch in php using links from a database using mysqli.

Operative $d

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $d = $_GET['page'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['page'])) { // Forms
    $d = $_POST['page'];
} else {
    $d = NULL;
}
```

The Switch

```
$sw1 = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$sw2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sw1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sw2)) {
    $page = $row['page'];

    switch($d) {

    case ''.$page.'':
        include 'modules/'.$page.'.php';
        break;

    default:
        include 'modules/main.php';
        break;
      }
}
```

This is not working, is there a different way to do this? idea is to allow URl's such as `/?page=thePage`

`$connection` is handled and connection to the database is confirmed so that is not the issue.

Any help is Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Don't use `switch`. Use `if-else` or `if-elseif-else` instead.

```php
$sw1 = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$sw2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sw1);
$found = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sw2)) {
    $page = $row['page'];

    if ($d === $page) {
        include 'modules/'.$page.'.php';
        $found = true;

        break;
    }
}

if (!$found) {
    include 'modules/main.php';
}
```

Comment: using this brings up every page  so when I go to / I see every module instead of just main.php or just echoes the main.php page multiple times...

Comment: @Keldo I see what you want. I updated my answer. This should work for you. You might also want to consider adding a ``WHERE`` statement to your query. But beware of SQL injections!  
Also please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Works great, super appreciate the help, I hadn't thought of using $finished.

Comment: @Keldo Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem.